# If the set on which a Riemann integrable function $f$ is nonzero has empty interior then the integral of $|f|$ is $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, riemann-integration

$f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is Rieman integrable and $X=\{x\in [a,b] : f(x)\neq 0\}$ has empty interior.

> show that $\int_a^b|f(x)|dx=0.$

I think that it is an easy exercise of measure theory. But how to solve it without the knowledge of measure theory and just using real analysis.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Dzoooks: That is not true, think of the irrationals in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a=x_0<x_1<...<x_n=b$ be a partition $P$ of $[a,b].$ Then since $X$ has empty interior, the lower Riemann sum
$$
L(f,P)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \min_{x\in[x_k,x_{k+1}]} |f(x)|\Delta_k=0.
$$
Take the supremum over all partitions $P$ and we have that the lower Riemann integral is zero. By integrability, the result follows.

Comment: I’m not the OP, but could you clarify why the supremum of the upper sums is 0? What if you took a partition which included a point from $X$ in each subinterval? Wouldn’t the upper sum then be strictly positive?

Comment: If an integral exists, it is not the supremum of upper sums. It is the infinimum of upper sums or supremum of lower sums (which are equivalent).

It is sufficient to show that the lower Riemann integral is zero since it equals the upper Riemann integral by integrability.

Comment: ah yes. Thanks. My real analysis is rusty.

Answer (score 4):

This is more like a comment regarding your remark about measure theory but it's too long so I'll put it here instead.

> The statement you want to prove is actually **false** if we interpret the word *integrable* in the Lebesgue sense.

Indeed, consider $[a,b] = [0,1]$ and let $X\subset [0,1]$ be the [fat Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set). $X$ is a closed set (hence measurable) with empty interior but has positive measure, so the function
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 &; x\in X \\
0 &; x\notin X\end{cases}
$$ 
is integrable, the set $\{x\in [0,1] : f(x)\neq 0\}$ has empty interior **but** $\int_0^1 |f(x)| dx>0$.

However, the above $f$ is not *Riemann integrable*. The statement you're trying to prove most likely is about Riemann integration.

Comment: Sorry for over-complicated things. Actually $X = \Bbb Q^c \cap [0,1]$ will do just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes yiu are right abiut my case. It is Riemannian integrable.  My mistake. I corrected it.