# Integral equals zero and empty interior

Tags: real-analysis, integration, general-topology, functions, riemann-integration

While trying to prepare for my Real Analysis exam I encoutered the following exercise:

**Problem:** Let $f:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be Riemann integrable. If the set $$
X=\{x \in[a, b] ; f(x) \neq 0\}
$$ has empty interior (notation: $\operatorname{int}(x)=\varnothing$) then $$\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)| d x=0$$

**What have i tried?** I started by trying to write what empty interior means and it went like this:

Since $\operatorname{int}(x)=\varnothing$ there does not exist $\epsilon > 0$ such that $$(\bar{x}-\varepsilon, \bar{x}+\varepsilon) \subset X$$ which means that $\forall \epsilon > 0$:

$$(\bar{x}-\varepsilon, \bar{x}+\varepsilon) \cap X^{c} \neq \varnothing$$

Let's call it $z$ the element in the set $(\bar{x}-\varepsilon, \bar{x}+\varepsilon) \cap X^{c}$

Since $z$ is in the intersection of the aforementioned set, we have that $z \in X^{c}$ and therefore $$\left\{\begin{array}{l}z \in[a, b] \\ f(z)=0\end{array}\right.$$

Finally, one is able to infer that $|z-\bar{x}|<\varepsilon$ since $z \in (\bar{x}-\varepsilon, \bar{x}+\varepsilon)$

**But now I am stuck.** I did find the same exercise already answered here [If the set on which a Riemann integrable function $f$ is nonzero has empty interior then the integral of $|f|$ is $0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3226247/if-the-set-on-which-a-riemann-integrable-function-f-is-nonzero-has-empty-inter) but i am looking forward to someone looking at what i have tried so far. Also, **i am very curious to know whether one can finish the exercise using what i have already done.**

Thanks in advance, Lucas

Comment: What you’ve done so far is what justifies the assertion in the other answer that $$\min_{x\in[x_k,x_{k+1}]} |f(x)|=0$$ for each subinterval of any partition of $[a,b]$. In effect you’ve shown that any subinterval of any partition contains a point $z$ such that $f(z)=0$. Thus, you could continue by giving a more completely justified version of the earlier answer.

Comment: Interesting. I just dont get why what i did justifies the assertion, i am afraid i am missing something simple. Could you explain it in further details?

Comment: You’ve proved that every subset of $[a,b]$ with non-empty interior (and hence every subinterval of every partition of $[a,b]$) contains a point $z$ such that $f(z)=0$. Thus, the minimum value of $f(z)|$ for $z$ in such a subset is $0$, since an absolute value cannot be negative. And that is precisely what is needed to conclude that every lower sum is $0$: the minimum value of $|f(z)|$ on each subinterval is $0$, so each subinterval contributes $0$ to the lower sum.

Comment: "You’ve proved that every subset of [a,b] with non-empty interior..." but $X$ had empty interior

Comment: Oh, is the set that has non-empty interior $X^{c}$? Since $X$ has empty interior and $X \in [a, b]$ then $X^{c}$ has non-empty interior(is that it?)

Comment: You showed that $X$ does not contain any open interval, so each open interval must contain a point of $[a,b]\setminus X$, i.e., a point where the function value is $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

Brian M. Scott has answered your question in his comments. Let $[r,s]$, $r < s$, be any closed subinterval of $[a,b]$. Then $\inf_{x \in [r,s]} \lvert f(x) \rvert = 0$; otherwise $(r,s) \subset X$ which would show that $X$ has non-empty interior. Hence for each
partition $P = (x_0,\ldots, x_n)$ of $[a,b]$ the lower sum is
$$L(\lvert f \rvert;P) = \sum_{i=1}^n \inf_{x \in [x_{i-1},x_i]} \lvert f(x) \rvert (x_i - x_{i-1}) = 0 .$$
Since $f$ is Riemann integrable, also $\lvert f \rvert$ is and we get
$$\int_a^b \lvert f(x) \rvert dx = \sup_P L(\lvert f \rvert;P) = 0 .$$